# Get SharePoint user ID and profile of an SP site with MS graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to get user ID inside a SharePoint site with Microsoft Graph API ?

I get a guid id with /me endpoint but in my SP site the current user has id 033.

I know there is a way with SP rest api with currentspcontext. But i want to query with ms graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Microsoft Graph currently only lets you query SharePoint sites, lists, and list items.  Have you tried using the Microsoft Graph to query the User Information list?

Here is a sample of the service call that you need.  You'll need to provide your user information list's guid and the Display name of the user.
//graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{user info list guid}/items?$select=Fields&$filter=Fields/Title eq 'Alex Wilber'&$expand=Fields

Comment: Please edit the answer and add a comment why you included the link.

Comment: Thank you Jason, this solution is not elegant but it has the merit of working. It's too bad there's no way to get past the /me endpoint. Maybe the best solution in this case would be to go through the OID that is in the JWT token, but in my case it's an existing project so I can't do it.

Comment: The Graph Community library added support for EnsureUser in v1.17.1.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Graph.Community/1.17.1-preview1

The Id returned by EnsureUser is the value to use when setting the lookup id.