# Using Graph API how to write Sharepoint "Person or Group" field?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint Online list with a column of type "Person or Group". I want to make a new entry for such a column using the Microsoft Graph API (eventually from a Teams bot).

My problem is that such a column holds a lookup value into something and I don't know how to get this number. I can successfully get a user object from Graph (/me or /users) but the object returned has an id which is something completely different. How do I link this to what Sharepoint Online requires?

Example: Sharepoint column `SG_Responsible` of type "Person or Group" as returned by Graph (note it is reported as `SG_ResponsibleLookupId`):

```
      "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"e2977d91-fd6d-4141-8bc6-897f5bbe9840,1\"",
                "Title": "Test 2",
                "SG_ResponsibleLookupId": "12",
                "SG_Description": "This is a Test",
       ...
```

The corresponding user from `/users`:

```
        {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "John Doe",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "john@example.com",
            "id": "76a3b5b7-768b-4dde-ba13-6d471aa2c7fd"
        },
```

So how to figure out that this user is user #12 for Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following guide:
https://dev.to/manuelsidler/create-a-sharepoint-list-item-with-a-people-lookup-field-using-microsoft-graph-sdk-4ad

It's written by Manuel Sidler and he is using the C# Graph SDK.

> ### The Solution
>
> There's a way with Microsoft Graph. A bit quirky, to be honest, but at least we don't have to use a SharePoint API and stay inside our Graph bubble.
> First, we have to fetch the id of the hidden user lookup list:
>
> ```cs
> var hiddenUserListId = (await _graph
>    .Sites["<siteid>"]
>    .Lists
>    .Request()
>    .Filter("displayName eq 'User Information List'")
>    .GetAsync())[0].Id;
> ```
>
> Next we have to get the user principal name if we don't have it yet:
>
> ```cs
> var userName = (await _graph
>    .Users[userId]
>    .Request()
>    .Select("userPrincipalName")
>    .GetAsync()).UserPrincipalName;
> ```
>
> With the user principal name in hand, we now can query the lookup id:
>
> ```cs
> var userLookupId = (await _graph
>    .Sites["<siteid>"]
>    .Lists[hiddenUserListId]
>    .Items
>    .Request()
>    .Header("Prefer", "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly")
>    .Filter($"fields/UserName eq '{userName}'")
>    .GetAsync())[0].Id;
> ```
>
> The prefer header with HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly is required to query non-indexed columns.
> And finally, we can create a new expense list item:
>
> ```cs
> var expenseItem = new ListItem
> {
>    Fields = new FieldValueSet
>    {
>        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
>        {
>            {"Title", "Train to Zurich"},
>            {"Amount", 23.2},
>            {"EmployeeLookupId", userLookupId}
>        }
>    }
> };
> await _graph
>    .Sites["<siteid>"]
>    .Lists["Expenses"]
>    .Items
>    .Request()
>    .AddAsync(expenseItem);
> ```

Comment: Did this work for you? The call works but no Employee shows up in my list Item. Weird.

Comment: Thank you, but this work only for user that already exist in User Information List.  Now I need to add a new employee from Azure AD to this field, but he is new to this site, not in this user list.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

User ID is site collection specific, you could get by SharePoint REST api, while no graph api for this based on my testing.

```
_api/web/siteusers
```

Checked [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443247/get-sharepoint-user-id-and-profile-of-an-sp-site-with-ms-graph-api) while not working.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Could you elaborate on the second part? I don't quite understand it.
I am able in the meantime to access all system lists `/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$select=system,id,name` and pick the id of the list called `users`. Unfortunately, the users I find by querying that `users` system lists don't have an id anywhere that corresponds to what I have to enter into the sharepoint list.

Comment: The Graph Community library added support for EnsureUser in v1.17.1.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Graph.Community/1.17.1-preview1

The Id returned by EnsureUser is the value to use when setting the lookup id.

Comment: It's been a long time since I actually did it but `ensureUser` is what I ended up with using.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint REST API should be able to give you the user id in the site collection you are working.

Replace the values with corresponding values.

SharePointWebURL/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Email eq 'UserEmail'&$select=Id

Then you should be able to get the user **Id** that you would be able to use to validate lookup field value.